# How to take instance function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i m new to angular and i m using angular for my project. I dont know how to take instance function from original.

My Function is blw

```
    $scope.collapsedrow = true;
    $scope.PlusClick = function(event) {
          $scope.collapsedrow = false;
          $scope.expandedrow = true;

    };
    $scope.MinusClick = function(event) {
          $scope.collapsedrow = true;
          $scope.expandedrow = false;
    };
```

I have so many rows. All rows are expandable/collapsible. When i click  PlusClick function in any row, it wil reveal the corresponding hided rows. The same for all other rows. now i can use it for only one row as it affects globally.

Can you help me to resolve it

Comment: Maybe you should think about store the flag collapsedrow and expandedrow at row level rather than at a global level.

Comment: how you output rows? can you provide html?

Comment: could u provide any code sample in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for each row, they need to have a special property.

```
app.controller('AppController',
[
  '$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [
      {id: 1, Name:'John',visible:true},
      {id: 2,Name:'Mark',visible:true},
      {id: 3,Name:'Sam',visible:true},
      {id: 4, Name:'Edward',visible:true},
      {id: 5, Name:'Michael',visible:true}
    ];

    $scope.collapsedrow = true;
    $scope.PlusClick = function(item) {
          item.visible = true;

    };
    $scope.MinusClick = function(item) {
          item.visible = false;
    };

  }
]
);

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-show="person.visible">
    {{person.Name}}
    <button ng-click="PlusClick(person)">+</button>
    <button ng-click="MinusClick(person)">-</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rf00VLhETU8F3IwW1ubD?p=preview)